# How to deal with Orange cloud /OIDC token random expiration?

Tags: cloud, openid-connect, orange

I am trying to use the cloud API from Orange and after an apparently random period of time, the token does not seem to work anymore. I am a bit lost between the opened connect documentation and the Orange implementation. Is there a way to reactivate it without asking the user to reconnect?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about access tokens as issued by [this API doc](https://www.orangepartner.com/content/api-reference-identity#posttoken-obtain), the token response will contain an `expires_in` field telling you how long the token is valid for. This is part of the [OAuth2 standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.4).

If a refresh token is also supplied as part of the response, it can be used to obtain a new access token.

It would probably help if you expanded your question to give more information on what APIs you're actually calling - is it just an OpenID connect request or is the access token used for calls to other API endpoints?

Answer (score 0):

According Orange Cloud API doc, refresh token is valid for one year.